# C# - How do I invoke a method on a different thread from a Timer's Elapsed event?

Tags: c#, timer, multithreading

I have a `System.Timers.Timer` object, and within its Elapsed method I want to call `myObject.TriggerEvent(...)`, but I want that invocation to happen on the thread `myObject` was created on. Is there an easy way to do this? And is this a bad idea for any reason? `myObject` is basically an event manager service, so I want it to trigger events on the thread it was created on. The reason I'm using the timer is because I have another that is polling a service for updates, which it notifies `myObject` of via the `TriggerEvent` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) implementation and provide its instance to the caller of `myObject.TriggerEvent`. If you're using `myObject` in WPF, SL or WinForms application, you can use their existing implementations of SynchronizationContext class and create `myObject` on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx). It was created in the context of WPF, but there is no reason it can't be used elsewhere. I've used it in a couple of times, but I always had a message pump (Win32), but I believe that it can be used in service contexts as well (IIS, etc) - however I have not written such code, so YMMV. [This is a good article from a WPF angle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).

Erick